# Meteor routing with a session id

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to build a cart system without the user having to login.

I'm using ironrouter

```
 Router.route('/cart', {
  template: 'cart',
  data: {
    cart: function () {
      return Carts.find({uid: Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId}).fetch();
      //return Carts.find({uid: "97gxA35vEAS63qsCR"}).fetch();
    }
  }
})
```

In my router I've got a cart method, which returns results based on the current session id... Well thats what Im trying to do anyways :)

It doesn't look like

```
Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId
```

Is returning anything, can't think of a reason why though, it works in a client side file.

My routers are located within /lib/routers.js (typo correction)

If you need anymore information please do let me know, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to rely on undocumented features like `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` for that. You can just use a session variable for that to which you assign a random id if it is not yet set:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
   if (!Session.get('id')) {
      Session.set('id', new Mongo.ObjectID()._str);
   }
});

Router.route('/cart', {
  template: 'cart',
  data: {
    cart: function () {
      if (Session.get('id')) {
         return Carts.find({uid: Session.get('id')}).fetch();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can I have the startup method in a different file if so what it the normal standard? /lib/startup.js ??
Thank you so much for all the help

Comment: It seems when adding a session variable my application just crashes
'ReferenceError: Session is not defined'

Comment: Ahh After some research it seem this only works on the client side, I'm trying to pass it through on the server side. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: Yes, Session variables only exist on the client side. But your route is a client-side route, too, so it shouldn't matter. Just make sure it is in the `client` folder, or guarded by `if (Meteor.isClient)`.

Comment: Its still confuses me then why it is breaking in this file, Sorry i know this doesn't help you much. When ever I use Session.set.... in my router.js it crashes my application.  with 'ReferenceError: Session is not defined'

Comment: well, because it is executed on the server, isn't it? anything in `/lib/` is shared between client and server and will execute in both place (but in this case crash on the server). Just put it in `/client/` somewhere.

Comment: you are welcome! If you'd like to return the favor then please consider up-voting.

Comment: I would I don't have enough rep yet and still getting used to using stackoverflow like this :\ sorry when I have enough rep I'm going to go back through all my questions!!!

Comment: Thank you for all the help!!! one other thing ' Session.set('id', new Mongo.ObjectID()._str);' is different for every tab. which makes sense as it creating it on start up do you know of a way I can make it more consistant for the user very much like a PHP session?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a cookie. If so, then there should be a number of packages on atmosphere providing help with that. But I don't know exactly which and how.